# Hostname address

Tags: xubuntu, ip

How can I change my IP address on Ubuntu VMware ESXi?

When I use if config not working you told me It have to be installed, and I can’t installed it becuase I have no network access.

I want to change the highlighted ip to 10.10.120.200/24
[image]

Comment: No you don't. That's the loopback device. You don't want to change that.

Comment: How is your IP address set in tje first place? DHCP? Fix it on the DHCP Server.

Comment: You are missing the output that shows the Ethernet device.  Your image is cut off so all you are showing is the loopback, which you should never change.  Plus, the loopback is designed to not communicate with your network but more for communicating with itself.  It is a virtual interface that only works with the IP addresses of 127.0.0.1 thru 127.255.255.255.  It is not configurable to anything else.

Comment: I want to communicate with this VM from windows 10 through WinSCP, when I tried to figure out what my IP address I use  (hostname -i) command which is show me that address 127.0.1.1. I want to change my IP address to the same subnet for my windows PC which is 10.10.120.200, how to do that if ifconfig command not working?

Comment: The loopback or `lo` is not the interface to use.  You are missing on your screen shot something like `enps03` or something like `eth0`.  Just an interface that is the Ethernet connection.  Secondly, you need to make sure that your VM is setup in a Bridged configuration for the network so that it can be part of your actual 10.10.120.xxx network.